# Salvando pai e filho se ambos forem válidos no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho duas classes `Protocolo` e `Movimentacoes`, no salvamento de `Protocolo` eu crio uma nova `Movimentação`.

```
class Protocolo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movimentacoes
  after_create :movimentacao_inicial

  def movimentar(status, usuario, comentario = nil)
    usuario = Usuario.find(usuario) if usuario.is_a?(Integer)
    if movimentacoes.create(status: status, usuario: usuario, comentario: comentario).valid?
      update_columns(status_atual: status)
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def movimentacao_inicial
    movimentar('enviado', usuario)
  end

  validates_associated :movimentacoes
end
```

E classe Movimentacao

```
class Movimentacao < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :protocolo
  validates :usuario, :protocolo, presence: true
end
```

Então sempre que `Protocolo` for salva, devo criar uma nova `Movimentação` e atualizar o status corrente de `Protocolo` com o `status` da última `movimentação` criada.

**Problema:** Caso `Movimentacao` seja inválida, `Protocolo` já foi criado e não posso criar uma `movimentação` antes de criar um `protocolo`.

Alguém sabe alguma forma de contornar isso?

Comment: Você conseguiu analisar a reposta Luiz? Posso tentar ajuda-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na minha opinião a melhor coisa que você pode fazer é criar um form nested utilizando os campos da movimentacao na própria view do protocolo.

remova after_create do `protocolo.rb`

ou utilizar no `ProtocoloController.rb`

```
Protocolo.transaction do
  @protocolo.save
  @protocolo.movimentar
end
```

[transaction rails](http://markdaggett.com/blog/2011/12/01/transactions-in-rails/)

---

Outra maneira não usar o transaction e deixar o controller do mesmo jeito que está e fazer o `@protocolo.save` do controller salvar o `movimentações.build`

`movimentação.rb`

```
before_create :movimentacao_inicial

def movimentar(status, usuario, comentario = nil)
  usuario = Usuario.find(usuario) if usuario.is_a?(Integer)
  mov = movimentacoes.build(status: status, usuario: usuario, comentario: comentario)
  if mov.valid?
    self.status = status
    return true
  else
    self.errors.add(:base, 'error') # não tenho certeza se irá precisar, pois você não está chamando em um validate.
    return false
  end
end
```

o `@protocolo.save` irá verificar a validação da classe Movimentacao

Comment: Obrigado :D upvte